# expand wildcards "inside a command" instead of in the shell

Tags: shell, directory, wildcards

(This is a simplest working example of something in a much messier context.)

I have a directory `d` with files `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.wav`.
My current directory is somewhere else.

`ls d` reports `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.wav`, as it should.

But I want only `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`, so I try `ls d/*.txt`.

But that prepends a `d/` to each filename: `d/1.txt d/2.txt d/3.txt`, because the shell expanded the `*` before `ls` saw it.

To get my desired `1.txt 2.txt 3.txt`, I could `ls d | grep txt`, or `ls d/*.txt | xargs basename -a`, or even spawn a new shell: `(cd d; ls *.txt)`.  Is there a better way, less clunky, less vulnerable to gotchas and corner cases, to filter the output of `ls`?

Comment: If **find** command is available, then checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-only-get-file-name-with-linux-find

Comment: So, `find d -name \*.txt -printf "%f\n"` ?  Yes, that works.  Even though it shuffles the filenames, I'd accept it as an answer if you post it.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune, you can also post your answer and accept it too. If **stackexchange** doesn't allow, then let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the simplest way to do what you ask is:

```
$ ( cd d; ls *.txt )
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

that is happening inside a sub-shell `( ... )` so the directory change is not permanent, is valid only for the execution of the two commands.

A more robust version is:

```
$ ( cd d && ls -d -- *.txt )
1.txt  2.txt  3.txt
```

In which `ls` is not executed unless the directory change was successful, and `ls` lists directories instead of their content and doesn't take files whose name starts with a dash as on option.

---

If you don't mind changing the positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, etc.):
This is also relatively simple:

```
$ set d/*.txt
$ for f do printf '%s\n' "${f#d/}"; done
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

This will work in POSIX shells:

```
$ dash -c 'set d/*.txt; for f do printf "%s\n" "${f#d/}"; done'
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

---

You could use GNU find's `-printf`:

```
$ find d -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.txt" -printf "%f\n" | sort
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

But that is getting complex enough. Sorry, there is no more "simple" solutions AFAIK.

Comment: This "GNU find" solution improves on Vikyboss's comment.  Nice!

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
printf '%s\n' d/*.txt(:t)
```

`:t` like for csh history modifiers but here in a glob qualifier, gets you the *tail* of the file name.

Also:

```
files=(d/*.txt)
printf '%s\n' $files:t
```

In other Bourne-like shells, you could always do:

```
(cd d && printf '%s\n' *.txt)
```

Note that it doesn't fork a new shell, it creates a subshell environment. In most shell implementations, that subshell environment is implemented by forking a child process, but a new shell is not executed in there (it's not a new  shell, it's the same shell forked in a new process). Also note that if the last command in the subshell is an external command, most shells (not `bash` though) will not fork an extra process, so the total number of processes run will be the same as without the sub-shell environment.

`ksh93` doesn't fork for subshells. It does it by undoing the modifications done within the subshell upon exiting from it. So, there (where `printf` is also built-in), `(cd d && printf '%s\n' *.txt)` doesn't fork extra processes.

Also note that `ls` lists the files and **content** of directories it is being passed as arguments. Here, you don't need `ls` if it's just for printing the names given by the shell, but if you insist in using `ls`, you should pass the `-d` option so it doesn't list the content of directories:

```
(cd d && ls -d -- *.txt)
```